# iPad's default SelectAll not working on for HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I have HTML page and a textarea control in it as

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

when i typed something and choose ipad's default SelectAll option; then nothing gets selected.

Can you please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/KYMBS/ It works on mine.